# Pandas getting hung up on simple if statement

Tags: python, pandas, alignment, fasta, sequencing

I have been trying to align sequences of DNA with pandas, but for some reason the line

```
if mat[i][0] == mat[0][j]
```

is taking an extremely long time to compute. It's not frozen as I can test it and see it is calculating, but it takes way too long to fill up the matrix. Is  this an issue with pandas? Is there a better solution for getting the data like I want?

```
import numpy as np
from Bio import SeqIO
import pandas as pd

#Import the fasta files
seq1 = SeqIO.read("eyeless.fasta", "fasta")
seq2 = SeqIO.read("aniridia.fasta", "fasta")

#Initializes the matrix with blank values except for the top left corner which will be a 0
mat = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(seq1.seq)+2), columns=pd.Series(range(len(seq2.seq)+2)))
mat.loc[0] = pd.Series(list('x'+'x'+seq2.seq))
mat[0] = pd.Series(list('x'+ 'x'+seq1.seq))
mat[1][1] = 0

#Initialize the first row and first column
for i in range(2,len(seq2.seq)+2):
     mat[i][1] = mat[i-1][1] - 1 
for j in range(2,len(seq1.seq)+2):
     mat[1][j] = mat[1][j-1] - 1  

print(mat)
v1 = 0
v2 = 0

#This section of the code goes through the matrix and determines if there will be a match, mismatch, or gap     
for i in range(2,len(seq2.seq)+2):     
     for j in range(2,len(seq1.seq)+2):

         #Match found, calculate score from this
         if mat[i][0] == mat[0][j]:
             v1 = mat[i-1][j-1] + 2
             v2 = mat[i-1][j-1] - 1 
             mat[i][j] = max(v1,v2)


print("\nHere is the completed matrix:")            
print(mat)

print("\nThe optimal score is:")
print(mat[len(t)+1][len(s)+1])
```

The fasta file 'eyeless' is X79493 and 'aniridia' is AY707088 from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov.

I can print the matrix correctly at first, but after the double for loop it will take several minutes to compute. Here is an example of the output I'm getting so far:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5oZs.png) note this is just the beginning of the first

```
print(mat)
```

statement

Comment: You have a double loop there, what are the lengths of `seq1` and `seq2`?

Comment: seq2 is 2850 &  seq1 is 1271 I believe @QuangHoang

Comment: It makes sense that double loop over 3,622,350 pairings is going to take a while. I'm not sure what exactly is going on here without data. But it doesn't look like you're using pandas idiomatically. Maybe try not iterating over the dataframe twice. That's not what pandas was made for. There's probably build in pandas methods to accomplish what you want that takes advantage of things like vectorization.